# Empty lines are coloured differently from lines which have text on them and the current line in vim

Tags: vim, colors, neovim

As you can see in the image the selected line is black and the empty lines in the buffer are a different colour is there a way I can use the `highlight` command in order to make empty lines completely black like the selected line?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by highlighting this field:
`hi EndOfBuffer guibg=black`